# Python MySQL cursor freezes at end of loop

Tags: python, mysql

My (simple) code below freezes instead of exiting the loop nicely. I'm using Python 2.7 + mysql.connector on a MacBook.

Any ideas appreciated. Thanks.

```
sSQL = "select * from addresses"

oMySQLConfig = {
                'user': 'XXXXX',
                'host': 'XXXXX',
                'database': 'xxxxx',
                'raise_on_warnings': True,
                'charset': 'utf8mb4'
                }   

oConnection = mysql.connector.connect(**oMySQLConfig)

rsDocums = oConnection.cursor(dictionary=True)  
rsDocums.execute(sSQL)

row = rsDocums.fetchone()
while row is not None:
    print (row)
    row = rsDocums.fetchone()
```

Comment: Does it work if instead of a `while` loop, you use `for row in rsDocums.fetchall()`?

Comment: thanks for your reply. the thing is i cant really do that because my datasets are large...actually they are not *that* large (max 200,000 records) but it takes sssooo long to return from the query that I ended up using cursors.

Comment: i did try your suggestion, but as expected the query is taking aggesss returning...

Comment: Makes sense. Was mostly just trying to help narrow down your problem to whether it's `fetchone()` specifically causing issues or something about the query. You could also try `fetchmany()` to batch groups together.

Comment: Nah the query is sound - nothing special about the query - OK, the table is 3.3million rows, but that cant be the problem. its something in mysql.connector that seems to be the issue. ive done a Google on it but not really found anything. cant believe no one has come across this before...

Comment: Your code looks exactly like the example at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html so it should work.

Comment: How about `for row in rsDocums:`?

Comment: actually i tried the for loop first, that failed so i then reverted to the while loop in the example above. both exhibit the exact same behaviour.

Comment: when i use Ctrl+C it tells me its stuck at "  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 247, in recv_plain
    read = self.sock.recv_into(packet_view, rest)"

Comment: Have also made the changes suggested here http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74483 - but no joy still...

Comment: RESOLUTION: Do not use the DATE() function in the query - use mydate >= '2016-11-09 00:00:00' and mydate <= '2016-11-09 23:59:59'